# Validar path nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, estou a desenvolver um sistema de manipulação de ficheiros, e quero apenas que seja possível manipular pasta com um caminho absoluto por exemplo `/opt/file`. Ou seja só posso criar/editar/eliminar pastas nesse caminho.
quero validar que o path inicial é sempre /opt/file.

Qual é a melhor forma de o fazer?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que o caminho seja uma `string` você pode utilizar a função [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) para identificar se o índice é 0, ou seja, se a `string` em questão começa com o texto que foi fornecido. Ficaria algo neste sentido:

```
...
if (path.indexOf('/opt/file') === 0) {
  // Faz o que deve fazer com o arquivo
...
```

> [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
>
> O método `indexOf()` retorna o índice da primeira ocorrência do valor especificado em searchValue dentro do objeto `String` para o qual foi chamado, começando a busca a partir de `fromIndex`. Retorna -1 se o valor não for encontrado.
>
> [**Sintaxe**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Syntax)
>
> ```
> str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
> ```
>
> ***searchValue***
>
> Uma string representando o valor a ser buscado.
>
> ***fromIndex***
>
> A posição da string original a partir da qual a busca deve começar. Pode ser qualquer número inteiro. O valor padrão é 0. Se `fromIndex < 0` a string toda é percorrida (equivalente a passar 0). Se `fromIndex >= str.length`, o método irá retornar -1.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o problema apena adicionei mais uma barra ao fim `if (path.indexOf('/opt/dir/')`, para validar apenas a pasta dir. Se não caminhos como dir1, dirx também seriam válidos.